# Too many keys being added to ssh-agent in CentOS6 - how can I stop this?

Tags: ssh-agent

I was trying to debug an ssh problem `Too many authentication failures`, and find with `ssh -vv` that ssh is presenting lots of keys before falling back to try a password.

On investigation I find that these keys are added somehow with `ssh-agent` running from `startx` when  X11 is started.

I have a lot of keys in my `~/.ssh` directory for different machines, transferred through many system updates over the years. I had not even realized that `ssh-agent` was running.

I thought that `ssh-add`, per the manpage, would add by default just `id_dsa`, `id_rsa` and `identity`.
But somehow it is adding `BillBrewer.pub`, `JanStewer.pub`, `PeterGurney.pub`, `PeterDavy.pub`, `DanlWhiddon`, `HarryHawke.pub`, `OldUncleTomCobley.pub` as well, and presenting the whole lot on every login session when I expect to give a password. So sshd on the server decides that enough is enough and disconnects.

How can I control this behaviour ? Apart from removing my extra public keys from my .ssh directory and just keeping the private ones I need, but that's always been a convenient place to keep them in the past.

For that matter, how can I stop ssh-agent running if I want to ?

Is this a security issue ( sending keys to servers that are not supposed to get them) ?

I realize that I can override it on a per-session basis
with `-o PreferredAuthentications=password` but I'd prefer a systemic fix.

- more strangeness: I tried using `ssh-add -D` to remove all identities, or `ssh-add -d *.pub`, but when I use `ssh-add -l`, they are all still there.

CentOS release 6.5,
OpenSSH_5.3p1,
openssh-clients-5.3p1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well first off, keys are supposed to identify the client, not the remote server. Thus you should only have a very small number of keys (such as 1).

The official `ssh-agent` utility itself will only look for a few predefined names when looking for your keys (`~/.ssh/id_rsa` `~/.ssh/id_dsa` `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa` and `~/.ssh/identity`).
However there are other ssh key agents other than `ssh-agent`. You likely have a keyring daemon running (such as `gnome-keyring-daemon`). The keyring daemon is likely started by your desktop environment by default. Go poking around in your desktop environment session settings to turn it off.

You can also put `IdentitiesOnly=yes` in your `~/.ssh/config` file, but I wouldn't consider this the "right" answer.

In regards to sending extra keys to the server. No, this is not any sort of security risk.

Comment: Just found [q72644](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72644/ssh-add-d-doesnt-erase-stored-keys-from-the-ssh-agent?rq=1) and thence [dtek blog](http://dtek.net/blog/how-stop-gnome-keyring-clobbering-opensshs-ssh-agent-ubuntu-1204).

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. Can't keep editing the above comment it seems. Yes, gnome-keyring is running and seems to add all keys without asking. Killing it fixes my problem.